# AutoMapper - IncludeBase with ignore same named property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use IncludeBase. It seems that it has a problem with same named properties on base classes. These are not included from base mapping but auto-resolved. I'm using automapper version 4.2.

Situation similar to this one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MapperConfiguration conf = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<FooBase, FooModelBase>()
                .ForMember(e => e.Error, opt => opt.Ignore());

            cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooModel>()
                .IncludeBase<FooBase, FooModelBase>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = conf.CreateMapper();

        //works just fine
        FooModelBase fooModelBase = mapper.Map<FooModelBase>(new FooBase());

        //throws an exception
        FooModel fooModel = mapper.Map<FooModel>(new Foo());
    }
}

class FooBase 
{
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

class Foo : FooBase { }

class FooModelBase 
{
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

class FooModel : FooModelBase { }
```

I have expected, that application doesn't throw exception, but it does. Any advice how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The key here is how *AutoMapper* prioritizes possible sources on inherited mappings

As you can see in [this link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) in *Automapper GitHub Project*, when you includes inherited mappings additional complexity is introducted because there are multiple ways a property can be mapped.

The priority of these sources are as follows:

1. Explicit Mapping (using `.MapFrom()`)
2. Inherited Explicit Mapping
3. Ignore Property Mapping
4. Convention Mapping (Properties that are matched via convention)

So 'Inherited Ignore Property Mapping' are ignored or have less priority.

What happens here is that 'Convention Mapping' has higher priority and therefore the property still gets mapped.

You can fix this issue adding explicitly `Ignore()` in derived map configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Foo, FooModel>()
    .ForMember(e => e.Error, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .IncludeBase<FooBase, FooModelBase>();
```

Comment: So there is no other way to do it, either write mine own include base extension or explicitly add each ignore mappings from base class. That's quite sad.

Comment: @eCorke: Yes, they should add some way to define this kind of behavior